# How to count the number of missing values in each row in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the number of missing value in each row in Pandas dataframe.
I would like to split dataframe to different dataframes which have same number of missing values in each row.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can apply a count over the rows like this:

```
test_df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
```

test_df:

```
    A   B   C
0:  1   1   3
1:  2   nan nan
2:  nan nan nan
```

output:

```
0:  3
1:  1
2:  0
```

You can add the result as a column like this:

```
test_df['full_count'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
    A   B   C   full_count
0:  1   1   3   3
1:  2   nan nan 1
2:  nan nan nan 0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thx.

Answer (score 50):

When using pandas, try to avoid performing operations in a loop, including `apply`, `map`, `applymap` etc. That's slow!

A DataFrame object has two axes: “axis 0” and “axis 1”. “axis 0” represents rows and “axis 1” represents columns.

If you want to count the missing values in each column, try:

`df.isnull().sum()` as default or `df.isnull().sum(axis=0)`

On the other hand, you can count in each row (which is your question) by:

`df.isnull().sum(axis=1)`

It's roughly 10 times faster than Jan van der Vegt's solution(BTW he counts valid values, rather than missing values):

```
In [18]: %timeit -n 1000 df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit -n 1000 df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 329 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplist way:

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or, you could simply make use of the info method for dataframe objects:

```
df.info()
```

which provides counts of non-null values for each column.

Answer (score 4):

null values along the column,

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=0)
```

blank values along the column,

```
c = (df == '').sum(axis=0)
```

null values along the row,

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
```

blank values along the row,

```
c = (df == '').sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, np.nan],
...                    [np.nan, 3, 4],
...                    [1, 2,      3]])

>>> df
    0  1   2
0   1  2 NaN
1 NaN  3   4
2   1  2   3

>>> df.count(axis=1)
0    2
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will return integer value of total number of columns with missing value:

```
(df.isnull().sum() > 0).astype(np.int64).sum()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want count of missing values:

```
np.logical_not(df.isnull()).sum()
```